# How to run a python script on Google App Engine for multiple users?

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am creating a Gmail analytics app for our organization. There are two main tasks for this app. First, it will search the sales and customer success team's Gmail for contacts that we do not already have in our CRM. Second, it will analyze the sentiment of the email content to determine if the response is positive, negative, or neutral. I wrote a python script that connects to the Gmail API, pulls the necessary data, runs the responses through a NLP model, and finally uploads the output to BigQuery. I have tested the script on my own account using the oauth2 authentication flow and everything works great.

I'm a little lost on next steps. I think that I need to host the script on Google's App Engine, but I don't know how to get authentication from the entire sales and customer success team, store their credentials, and then set the script to run once a day.

Answer (score 1):

I will respond in three steps

1.Get authentication from the entire sales and customer success team.

You will need to get a one time only acknowledge of the user (enter their credentials) then accept your app to enter to their emails, then you will be able to enter to the Gmail API on behalf of the user. A more detailed explanation on server side authorization is [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/web-server#top_of_page)

2.Store teams credentials

As a oauth2 authentification is needed to access gmail API, the first time your app exchanges the authorization code, it also receives a refresh token that it uses to receive a new access token after a previous token has expired. Your application stores this refresh token (generally in a database on your server) for later use. [Detail info and example code.](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/web-server#exchange_the_authorization_code_for_an_access_token)

3.Set the script to run once a day

For that you will need a [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/), which will trigger a cloud function that will run your script, [here is an example](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/tut-pub-sub) or if its to heavy for a cloud function, it could the trigger the start/stop of a app engine instance or VM instance, here is an [example of this architecture](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/start-and-stop-compute-engine-instances-on-a-schedule).

Hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Could I use something like Firebase to get authentication and store credentials?

Comment: U want to us a SAML solution. I would love to know how u parse Gmail for new contacts in emails.

Comment: If you use firebase authentication, it takes acre of all of the credential saving, so Yes Firebase would be an option.